# Django - how to Install Python Image Library (PIL)

Tags: python, linux, django, installation, python-imaging-library

I want to use the ImageField for forms and according to the documentation, it said I need to install the Python Imaging Library:

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

It says that the current free version is PIL 1.1.7, so I decided to go for that. I am using Lubuntu (Linux) and the only Non-WindowsOnly installation is the

Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 Source Kit

so I decided to click and install that .tar.gz file. I know have the Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz file in my downloads folder. Can someone tell me / show me a site which explains how I can now link it with Django? Where should I extract the file?

Comment: `pip install pillow` https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about Pillow: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It is a fork of PIL, and Django supports if from 1.6, and prefers it over PIL. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19934

```
pip install Pillow
```

**Edit:**

As @miki725 noted, it was working even before 1.6, but it has been "officially" supported since.

Comment: I happily used pillow before Django 1.6. Django imports Pil's `Image` class using `from PIL import Image` which is still valid in pillow.

Comment: @frnhr "and Django supports if from 1.6" wait, I have Django 1.5, will it work for me?

Comment: @frnhr also, does it matter which directory I install Pillow? I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.6 and Lubuntu, if that matters.

Comment: @user2719875 it should, yes, give it a try. You should get familiar with virtualenv, but if you care to just get going, simply do the `pip` command and it will install Pillow system wide. No need to download source etc, really.

Comment: Pillow is a functional drop-in replacement for the Python Imaging Library and therefor works with any Django. See: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting-pil-to-pillow.html

Comment: @miki725 when I do 'from PIL import Image' in my models.py file, it gives an error saying 'No module named PIL' even though I did 'pip install Pillow'.. am I supposed to do anything else (like make changes to my setttings.py file maybe?) in order to be able to use the ImageField?

Comment: No. It should just work. if you already had PIL installed, that might cause issues

Answer (score 0):

source: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/

```
pip install Pillow
```

Pillow is the “friendly” PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors. PIL is the Python Imaging Library by Fredrik Lundh and Contributors.